# Delete folder path from text file with batch

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

Currently running a backup with batch file using robocopy and using the /log command to write the output to a text file. The log file only contains the folder path currently and would like to remove everything except the file name that was copied over.

```
robocopy "C:\Junk" "H:\Junk"/s /mov /log:"c:\New Junk\Junk (%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-2,2%).txt"  /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /NC /NP
```

Eventually I'll have multiple text files that will need to be searched for the path "C:\Junk" to be removed from them. I've tried Findstr, but with horrible results. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using a for loop with the /r switch. Here's the simple code

```
@ECHO OFF CD C:\Junk FOR /R %%G in (*.txt) DO ECHO %%~nG >> "H:\New Junk\Junk (%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-2,2%).txt" PAUSE
```

And then running the robocopy command without the